# How is the Assembly.Load(Assembly) never null?

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1

In NET Core 3.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load?view=netcore-3.1#System_Reflection_Assembly_Load_System_Reflection_AssemblyName_

How is the return value of Assembly.Load(Assembly) never null? The code hint I receive is that the expression (`Assembly.Load(Assembly) != null`) is always true. Is Assembly a reference type?

```
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    var appAssembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(env.ApplicationName));
                    if (appAssembly != null)
                    {
                        config.AddUserSecrets(appAssembly, optional: true);
                    }
                }
```

[image]

Comment: It looks (from the docs and your squiggly line) that it either returns a valid assembly, or it will throw an exception.  Note that there are a whole range of exceptions it might throw

Comment: Which IDE are you using? I can't get this in my VS(without resharper) , though Rider reports it.

Comment: As for why - possibly due to that if returned assembly could be null only in case of failure during load, which will result in exception.

Comment: I use Resharper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.NET Core:**

That's because of this line in the [source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/RuntimeAssembly.cs,347), which effectively tells the compiler this value is not null.  See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types#nullable-references-and-static-analysis) on the static code analysis here.

```
return retAssembly!;
```

So you'll get a non-null value or an exception.

**.NET Framework:**

That's because the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/assembly.cs,350) has a contract:

```
public static Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
{
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<Assembly>() != null);
    //More code
}
```

So you will either get a non-null return value, or an exception.

Comment: Your source code is for .NET Framework, .NET Core (which OP uses) [version](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/Assembly.CoreCLR.cs,e4d05405b4c63794) does not use code contracts

Comment: @GuruStron Edited